# Copying an array fails with sed (unterminated `s' command)

Tags: linux, bash, sed, command-line, array

i'm trying to copy an array from a running bash script to an external file, but i run into trouble with sed. After hours of searching i still couldn't find an answer, so i thought i post a question here.

```
ARRAY=( M4d W0rld )

sed '/^#/!s/ARRAY=(.*)/ARRAY=( '${ARRAY[@]}' )/g' test.txt
```

Results in:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated `s' command
```

While the following:

```
ARRAY=( M4d W0rld )

sed '/^#/!s/ARRAY=(.*)/ARRAY=( '$ARRAY' )/g' test.txt
```

Works as expected:

```
#test.txt    
ARRAY=( M4d )
```

The above is not what i want, but why is the first option failing?

Comment: There are spaces in `${ARRAY[@]}`, which terminate the `sed` command prematurely. Try surrounding `${ARRAY[@]}` with double-quotes.

Comment: By the way, `${ARRAY[@]}` is not the same as `$ARRAY`. The former expands to the entire array, the latter to the first element.

Comment: @berndbausch I knew the difference between the two, but why do spaces terminate the sed command prematurely?

Comment: Without double quotes, the shell expands `${ARRAY[@]}` to `M4d W0rld` first. The space is a delimiter, therefore it sends these arguments to sed: `/^#/!s/ARRAY=(.*)/ARRAY=( M4d`, `W0rld )/g` and of course `test.txt`. So, `sed`'s first argument is `/^#/!s/ARRAY=(.*)/ARRAY=( M4d`. The substitution command is not terminated.

Comment: With the double quotes, the space in `M4d W0rld` does not count as a delimiter, and `sed` receives this as first argument: `/^#/!s/ARRAY=(.*)/ARRAY=( M4d W0rld )/g`. Here, the substitution is properly terminated with a slash.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems i found the answer with a stroke of luck, this code works:

```
ARRAY=( M4d W0rld )

sed '/^#/!s/ARRAY=(.*)/ARRAY=( '"${ARRAY[*]}"' )/g' test.txt
```

The asterisk was very important apparently, but what is the difference with the @ symbol? Also why the extra double quotes?

Comment: I think the double quotes are the important ingredient here, and in this particular case there is no difference between `@` and `*` (however, the difference between the two is so subtle anyway that I might be wrong).

Comment: `"${ary[*]}"` expands into a single string. `"${ary[@]}"` expands into each separate element. Without quotes, word splitting and glob expansion will occur. See the Arrays section in the manual.

Comment: If you have bash version 5, use `sed '/^#/!s/ARRAY=(.*)/ARRAY=( '"${ARRAY[@]@Q}"' )/g' test.txt` -- that will make the elements properly quoted